# 419 error in second login after a logout in a SPA using Laravel API and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf-token

I'm getting a *page expired error* (er.419) when I try to login after a previous logout.

I'm working on auth pages for SPA made with Laravel and Vue.js. It works well on first login but after a logout it shows an error submitting the second one login.

I think the issue is the CSRF sent previously and (maybe) expired after logout.

My work flow is this:

login component has hidden form sent as POST method to Laravel API having the csfr-token value from an HTML META TAG set up when app is created by Laravel template:

> meta name="login-status" content="{{ Auth::check() }}"

The logout is done by a fetch request in a vue component. So no refresh is done.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Maybe there is a redirect somewhere?

Comment: Hmm the logout is done with a fetch:   fetch("/api/logout", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token,
                })
            }) then the laravel API complete the logout in backend. No refresh here.

Answer (score 2):

From the laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-introduction):

> Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

When you logout, you are invalidating your current session - which means that the csrf token you have cached in your meta becomes invalid.

**Solution 1**

Refresh the page when you successfully logout, so php can output the active csrf token into your meta tag. For example:

```
fetch('/api/logout', {
    method: 'post'
}).then(() => {
    window.location.href = '/login';
});
```

**Solution 2**

Consider using the `api` route middleware group. Doing so will mean the application will not trigger the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. Bear in mind though that you will no longer have access to the session, so you'll need to look into stateless authentication techniques such as via JWT's.

Laravel themselves even provide a package for authenticating api's. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack. You confirmed my thought about csrf.  At moment I'll go for solution 1. In meanwhile I'll keep a look at solution 2 which look interesting. Tanks for your time helping me.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem. Good luck :)